# is it possible to use a CA-Cert for serverauthentification in WPA enterprise networks with android 2.2+?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi, security, 2.3-gingerbread, certificates

I just wanted to know if it is possible with android 2.2+ to use a ca-cert for server auth in WPA-Enterprise networks?
A fried told me it is not possible, but this would mean there would be a mayor security hole in every android device, so I would like to know it for sure now: did they removed this important security feature or not?
I would check it by myself, but unfortunately I don't have a android 2.2 or 2.3 device.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've done this but I don't exactly remember.  Android certainly lets you use certificates.

Answer (score 3):

At least on 2.2.1 I can see the options to use certificates. First you have to install the certificates by placing them on your sdcard and using `Settings -> Location and security -> Install encrypted certificates`. Then you can add the network from `Settings -> Wireless and network -> Wi-Fi settings -> Add Wi-Fi network`. Select `802.1x EAP` as the security mode and then just configure the settings to work for your network. Can't test myself since we don't use WPA-Enterprise class security, but it should be this straightforward.